# Have text wrap image

Tags: html, css

I have a WordPress post that is to show the thumbnail and the blog text. The blog text is returned with a bunch of `<p>` tags. The HTML looks like below:

```
<div class="post-thumbnail" style="size:100px;">
   <a href="#">
   <img width="300" height="180" src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2018/tom-longboats-131st-birthday-5532989583785984-s.png" class="attachment-medium size-medium wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2018/tom-longboats-131st-birthday-5532989583785984-s.png 300w, https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2018/tom-longboats-131st-birthday-5532989583785984-s.png 1024w" sizes="100vw">                   </a>
</div>
<!-- .post-thumbnail -->
<p>
</p>
<p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing! The definitions can be applied to DIVs or OLs. Using Modernizer JS, you can prepend flex-capable browsers with the flexbox code + an element reset, and non-capable browsers with an ugly but functional solution using classic CSS.</p>
<p>Technically, you could also do it with a few lines of jQuery and a denounced resize function. It would be easier for you to set up, but harder on the browser.</p>
<p>Or you could use a combination of the three.</p>
<p>Or you could generate your widths as fluid percentages and control the display using media queries on font sizes, with covered backgrounds on image DIVs.The definitions can be applied to DIVs or OLs. Using Modernizer JS, you can prepend flex-capable browsers with the flexbox code + an element reset, and non-capable browsers with an ugly but functional solution using classic CSS.</p>
<p>Technically, you could also do it with a few lines of jQuery and a denounced resize function. It would be easier for you to set up, but harder on the browser.</p>
<p>Or you could use a combination of the three.</p>
<p>Or you could generate your widths as fluid percentages and control the display using media queries on font sizes, with covered backgrounds on image DIVs.</p>
<p></p>
```

I want to have the text wrap the image. The image should be on the right aligned. Here is a [sample](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_layout_float) that I have been able to create, but I fail to see how to do that same with my HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've already done the example successfully, the same CSS can do the job for your HTML:

```
<style>
img {
    float: right;
}
</style>
```

However, since in your HTML the image is inside a `div`, it's better to apply the CSS to the `div`. Something like:

```
<style>
.post-thumbnail {
    float: right;
}
</style>
```

If you don't want to apply it to the class, you can add an ID to the `div`. Here is a demo:

```html
<style>
.post-thumbnail {
    float: right;
}
</style>
<div class="post-thumbnail" style="size:100px;">
  <a href="#">
    <img width="300" height="180" src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2018/tom-longboats-131st-birthday-5532989583785984-s.png" class="attachment-medium size-medium wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2018/tom-longboats-131st-birthday-5532989583785984-s.png 300w, https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2018/tom-longboats-131st-birthday-5532989583785984-s.png 1024w"
      sizes="100vw"> </a>
</div>
<!-- .post-thumbnail -->
<p>
</p>
<p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing! The definitions can be applied to DIVs or OLs. Using Modernizer JS, you can prepend flex-capable browsers with the flexbox code + an element reset, and non-capable browsers
  with an ugly but functional solution using classic CSS.</p>
<p>Technically, you could also do it with a few lines of jQuery and a denounced resize function. It would be easier for you to set up, but harder on the browser.</p>
<p>Or you could use a combination of the three.</p>
<p>Or you could generate your widths as fluid percentages and control the display using media queries on font sizes, with covered backgrounds on image DIVs.The definitions can be applied to DIVs or OLs. Using Modernizer JS, you can prepend flex-capable browsers
  with the flexbox code + an element reset, and non-capable browsers with an ugly but functional solution using classic CSS.</p>
<p>Technically, you could also do it with a few lines of jQuery and a denounced resize function. It would be easier for you to set up, but harder on the browser.</p>
<p>Or you could use a combination of the three.</p>
<p>Or you could generate your widths as fluid percentages and control the display using media queries on font sizes, with covered backgrounds on image DIVs.</p>
<p></p>
```